# Error: EACCES: permission denied, open .audit.json

Tags: node.js, linux, winston

I was trying to implement the winston logger along with winston-daily-rotate-file in my angular application with node.js.

code worked fine in local windows environment, but while i was moving to higher env in linux, I am getting the below permission error while starting my application by executing "node server.js"

Please help whether issue is with permission or something else

```
'[FileStreamRotator] Failed to store log audit at:' '//.audit.json' 'Error:' { Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '//.audit.json'
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:646:18)
at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:1299:33)
at Object.FileStreamRotator.writeAuditLog (/apps/app/node_modules/file-stream-rotator/FileStreamRotator.js:244:12)
at Object.FileStreamRotator.addLogToAudit (/apps/app/node_modules/file-stream-rotator/FileStreamRotator.js:318:27)
at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/apps/app/node_modules/file-stream-rotator/FileStreamRotator.js:432:34)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:211:7)
at /apps/app/node_modules/file-stream-rotator/FileStreamRotator.js:478:20
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
errno: -13,
code: 'EACCES',
syscall: 'open',
path: '//.audit.json' }
```

part of Server.js

```
  const winston = require('winston');
   const winstonRotator = require('winston-daily-rotate-file');
   const { combine, timestamp, label, printf } = winston.format;
   var rotatorOptions = {
    level: 'info',
    filename: './logs/app-%DATE%.log',
    datePattern: 'MM-DD-YYYY',
    handleExceptions: true,
    zippedArchive: false,
    maxsize: '10m', 
    maxFiles: '15d',
   };
   const logger =winston.createLogger({
    format: combine(
    label({ label: 'APP' }),
    timestamp(),
    printf(info => {return `${info.timestamp} [${info.label}] ${info.level}: 
    ${info.message}`; })
 ),
 'transports': [ new winstonRotator(rotatorOptions) ]
});
```

OS : Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.5 (Maipo)

Comment: Does the node process have file system access to the `./logs/` folder?

Comment: Was also thinking that @jschnurr , looks like the node process does not have permissions to access the file/dir

Comment: The configured log filename is `./logs/app-%DATE%.log` but the error message states, that writing to `//.audit.json` is not possible. So somewhere in your configuration, there must be `//.audit.json` configured and this is `/` where the app when run as non root has no access.